# Php Web service client returning std class

Tags: php

I am new to php. I have created a webservice in .Net and trying to consume it in Php. The code i have written to consume the web service is as follows:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:50207/Airthmatic.asmx?WSDL");
$helloWorldObj =  (Array)$client->HelloWorld();
echo $helloWorldObj["HelloWorldResult"];
```

My question is why the return value from the webservice is converted to a std class? I have to convert it to an array to be able to get the Hello World value. Is this the right approach?

Comment: what `format` does the web-service you created return the data in?

Answer (score 0):

You could access the element of your stdClass with the -> operator.

`$helloWorldObj->HelloWorldResult;` would do the same :)